# Contact lookup based on Customer selection

Tags: acumatica

I need to create a Contact lookup in SO screen (SO301000). I have already created user defined custom field as below. I is listing all contacts but it is not refreshing based on when select customer. Do I have to write any event for CustomerID to refresh these Contact lookup? Does anyone has any idea?

```html
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact")]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
 LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>>),
 DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true, DirtyRead = true)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactInactive, typeof(Contact.displayName))]
[PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(Contact.contactID))]
public virtual int? UsrCustContactID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustContactID : IBqlField { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Where Clause and you need to use `BAccount2` instead of `BAccount`. `SOOrderEntry` Graph has data view defined with `Vendor` DAC which gets initialized first/before `BAccount` and framework will substitute it with `Vendor` DAC. To prevent this, you need to use `BAccount2` DAC in your BQL.

```c
    using System;
    using PX.Data;
    using PX.Objects.SO;
    using PX.Objects.CR;

    namespace DemoPkg
    {
        public class SOOrderPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOOrder>
        {
            #region UsrContactID

            public abstract class usrContactID : IBqlField { }

            [PXDBInt()]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
            [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
                LeftJoin<BAccount2, On<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>>),
                DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true, DirtyRead = true)]
            [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            [PXFormula(typeof(Default<CRCase.customerID>))]
            [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.contactType, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>,
                    And<Where<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
                            Or<Current<SOOrder.customerID>, IsNull>>>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactBAccountDiff)]
            [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactInactive,
                          typeof(Contact.displayName))]
            public virtual Int32? UsrContactID { get; set; }

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

And make sure you have `AutoRefresh` set to `true` in aspx for PXSelector control of this field.

Comment: That worked BAccount2 did the trick here, Contact lookup is now refreshing based on Customer selected. However, if I try to modify existing Order and remove Customer or change, then application just hung. I have to refresh my browser.

Comment: I don't see such issue at my end. Please remove all other customization you may have on this site, and try with just this customization.

Comment: Thanks Dhiren. It seems it was because of another customization.

Comment: correlated to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921902/populate-custom-field-while-creating-sale-order-from-opportunity/43925100?noredirect=1#comment75544197_43925100), when I create a SO from Opportunity, these Contact lookup does not get populate from Opportunity. However, I have a different set of code for Contact lookup, if I use that then it does populate the Contact from Opportunity but then it does not refresh based on Customer selection in SO. Any idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I see you do not have a where condition in your selector to be based on the given customer. Try updating your selector to match something like this...

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
    LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>,
    Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>>>),
DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true, DirtyRead = true)]
```

In your page also make sure your selector has AutoRefresh="true"

Example:

```
<px:PXSelector ID="edWeightUOM" runat="server" 
    DataField="WeightUOM" Size="S" AutoRefresh="true" />
```

Comment: Here is what I already have it for selector

`<px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector145" DataField="UsrCustContactID" TextField="displayName" FilterByAllFields="True" DisplayMode="Text" TextMode="Search" AutoRefresh="True" AllowEdit="True" CommitChanges="True" />`

Comment: you need the selector to have a where statement.. let me look for an example

Comment: added selector example (didn't test it) but if you want a selector to be based off of another field, you need to use it in the where statement and use Current to point to the given field(s) that would contain the value in the current cache.