# Populate custom field while creating sale order from opportunity

Tags: acumatica

I have created a custom field Contact on SO screen (SO301000). Now I need to populate these field when user Create Sales Order from Opportunity screen (CR304000). New custom field Contact is based on Customer selected in Opportunity. I can see that Customer is automatically populated when I create Sales Order from Opportunity as it is by designed. However, how can I  do that same for the custom field.

I have tried extending existing CreateSalesOrder method but it seems it is not helping.

Contact Lookup (It refreshes based on Customer select in SO but not when I create SO from Opportunity)

```html
[PXDBInt()]

[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID,
 LeftJoin<BAccount2, On<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>>),
 DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true, DirtyRead = true)]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Default<SOOrder.customerID>))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.contactType, NotEqual<ContactTypesAttribute.bAccountProperty>,
  And<Where<BAccount2.bAccountID, Equal<Current<SOOrder.customerID>>,
    Or<Current<SOOrder.customerID>, IsNull>>>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactBAccountDiff)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), PX.Objects.CR.Messages.ContactInactive,
     typeof(Contact.displayName))]

public virtual int? UsrCustContactID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustContactID : IBqlField { }
```

Contact Lookup (It is working as required when I create SO from Opportunity but does not refreshes based on Customer selection)

```html
[PXDBInt()]

[PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(Contact.contactID))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Contact.isActive, Equal<True>>), "Contact '{0}' is inactive or closed.", new[] { typeof(Contact.displayName) })]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<Contact.contactID, LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Contact.bAccountID>>>, Where<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.person>, Or<Contact.contactType, Equal<ContactTypesAttribute.lead>>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(Contact.displayName), Filterable = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contact")]


public virtual int? UsrCustContactID { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustContactID : IBqlField { }
```

Comment: you should be able to do something similar as found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352177/how-to-pass-line-item-custom-field-value-to-sales-order-from-opportunity

Comment: Which event handler I should write that code into OpportunityMaintExtension. I tried with CROpportunity_RowPersisting and DoCreateSalesOrder method. But none of this is hitting the code when I click on Actions > Create Sales Order

Comment: Based on length of response, i will add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar answer found here: [How to pass line item custom field value to sales order from opportunity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352177/how-to-pass-line-item-custom-field-value-to-sales-order-from-opportunity)

Can be translated to something like this from CROpportunity to SOOrder...

```
public class CROpportunityMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public virtual void DoCreateSalesOrder(Action del)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>(graph =>
        {
            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<SOOrder>((cache, args) =>
            {
                var soOrder = (SOOrder)args.Row;
                CROpportunity opportunity = PXResult<CROpportunity>.Current;

                // Copy logic here...

            });
        });

        del();
    }
}
```

Comment: DoCreateSalesOrder we cannot override. I kind of kept the code in CROpportunity_RowSelected event handler, but seems it is not working. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why can you not override? The answer shows you have you override and I use this same logic in a customization project to add data from an opportunity to sales order today. What issues are you having with using the included answer?

Comment: I can override as you suggested and it is working. However, as I had mentioned that Contact field is custom field in SO and it is lookup which refreshes based on the Customer selection as per the solution in below link
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228334/contact-lookup-based-on-customer-selection). I have included the lookup code in the original post. Let me know your suggestions.

Comment: this sounds like a different question, but if i under stand correctly, you do NOT want the value to change based on the customer when the order is created from an Opportunity?

Comment: I want the Contact should be populated correctly when I create SO from Opportunity but at the same time if I Contact lookup should show only those related contact based on the Customer. So that if user goes directly to create SO and when they selects Customer, Contact lookup should refresh accordingly and show only those contact which are related to selected Customer.

Comment: I see you submitted your update against my answer. You should update your original question and not my answer with your additional question.

Comment: When you create the Order from opportunity, does the selector on the sales order not show the correct values BEFORE or AFTER the users saves the order (or neither). Possibly you need auto refresh on the selector field? I assume the value is not automatically set or should it be?

Comment: When I create an Order from Opportunity, the selector does show the correct value. However, if I do lookup, it shows all the contacts instead of only related contact under that customer.

Comment: If the problem is with the selector showing the incorrect results in the selector window, you should respond to that question which you have posted in the link and already marked as the answer. This post was about setting a value on sales order when created from an opportunity which you mentioned the value is being set when the order is created.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Brendan for your help. I have posted it on another thread.

Comment: sounds good. Don't forget if the answer is helped you resolve the question, to mark it as answered to close out the question. Looking at the comment in the other link however you are saying you are not able to copy the value so I find the real issue you are having very confusing.